# All entries in slice end up identical after copying from another slice

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I have a slice of `uuid.UUID` elements. From [the source](https://github.com/google/uuid/blob/master/uuid.go#L20), a `uuid.UUID` is just a type alias for a byte array: `type UUID [16]byte`.

I'm trying to convert this slice of `uuid.Uuid`s to a slice of `[]byte` using the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/google/uuid"
)

func main() {
    ids := []uuid.UUID {
        uuid.New(),
        uuid.New(),
        uuid.New(),
    }
    fmt.Printf("ids: %v\n", ids)
    idBytes := make([][]byte, len(ids))
    for i, id := range ids {
        idBytes[i] = id[:]
    }
    fmt.Printf("idBytes: %x\n", idBytes)
}
```

[playgroud link](https://play.golang.com/p/Zb2xuDttlmU)

For some reason, this produces the following output:

```
ids: [66b4bb26-3c1f-4dd7-a608-aa8f799e4bfe 014e0537-c326-4021-be38-165f49595eed 5c71efff-ddb5-4f6e-8f85-c1dab013b5d1]
idBytes: [5c71efffddb54f6e8f85c1dab013b5d1 5c71efffddb54f6e8f85c1dab013b5d1 5c71efffddb54f6e8f85c1dab013b5d1]
```

There are clearly 3 distinct UUIDs, but the output slice contains only the last one, repeated 3 times. What's going on here?

Things I've tried:

1. Use a non-slice type instead of a slice type (that is, use []uint64 as input and output instead of []uuid.UUID and [][]byte). This shows the expected behavior (I see 3 distinct values instead of the last value repeated 3 times), but it doesn't actually solve my problem.
2. Set only the last element (put the `idBytes[i] = id[:]` inside an `if i == len(ids) - 1` block). This sets only the last element (the first two elements remain nil).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two facts to consider:

- `id` is of type UUID, which is `[16]byte`.
- Loop variables a overwritten at each iteration

Thus, there is only one instance of `id` is allocated and shared between all iterations of the for loop. Since `id` is an array (not a slice), contents of each UUID are copied to `id`. All the slices `id[:]`, thus, point to the same shared underlying byte array, which, when the loop ends, contains the latest contents of `id`.

To fix:

```golang
idBytes[i] = ids[i][:]
```

which will create separate slices for each UUID.

Comment: Gotcha -- so the reason the example works with `uint64` is that Go was copying the actual `uint64` value into `idBytes[i]`, whereas with `[]byte` it just copies the address of `id` (which is *not* the address of `ids[i]`). Thanks!

Comment: It does *not* copy the address of `id`. It copies the 16-byte UUID to `id`, and all the slices produced in the loop have the common underlying array, which is `id`.

Comment: You're right, I should have been more precise. All of the slices will use the data located at the address of `id`, rather than using the data at the address of `ids[i]`.